# Date difference between events in same column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am new to MS SQL and I am having difficulty in getting correct results. I currently have a table with headers `updateddate`(date), `addedby`(number),  `operationid`(number) and `servicereqno`(number) that have been selected from three different tables.

The `operationid` is an event and the `servicereqno` is a job number. I want to be able to get a time difference taken between events and then once this is established calculate the average.

For example:

- opid 512 is at 20:15 - servicereqno 1
- opid 535 is at 21:23 - servicereqno 1

My first task will be to determine what the difference in time is, ensuring it is within the same job number.

Many thanks

Comment: this is now the syntax i have entered however it is not working: the first stop now is based on highlighted area which it states is an 'Invalid object name' i don't understand why this is invalid when it is the object name:

Comment: select CHANGE.UPDATEDDATE, CHANGE.ADDEDBY, S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID, CHANGE.SERVICEREQid
FROM CHANGE INNER JOIN CHANGE_H ON CHANGE.SERVICEREQNO = CHANGE_H.SERVICEREQNO INNER JOIN
S_OPERATION ON CHANGE_H.OPERATIONID = S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID
WHERE  (S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID = 102005212) OR
 (S_OPERATION.OPERATIONID = 102005218) or
 (s_operation.operationid = 102005406) or (s_operation.operationid = 102005401) or
(s_operation.operationid = 102005215); WITH cteOps AS (

Comment: SELECT row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY change.servicereqno ORDER BY change.updateddate) seqid, change.updateddate, change.servicereqno  FROM **CHANGE.updateddate, change.addedby, s_operation.operationid, change.servicereqno)**
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, o1.updateddate, o2.updateddate) updateddatediff, servicereqno  FROM cteOps o1  JOIN cteOps o2 ON o1.seqid=o2.seqid+1 AND o1.servicereqno=o2.servicereqno;

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the timespan between events, you need to number all operations sequentially (one increments without leftout), and then join that on itself with an offset of 1. You'll get n-1 rows as result with the timespan inbetween.

Something like this:

```
WITH cteOps AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY servicereqno ORDER BY updateddate) seqid, updateddate, servicereqno
  FROM yourdatasource
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(millisecond, o1.updateddate, o2.updateddate) updateddatediff, servicereqno
  FROM cteOps o1
  JOIN cteOps o2 ON o1.seqid=o2.seqid+1 AND o1.servicereqno=o2.servicereqno;
```

Of course you can perform aggregates on that to get the average or whatever you need.

Comment: The question of the OP is a little vague on this, but I think you would need a `ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY servicereqno ORDER BY updateddate) AS seqid`. Otherwise you are comparing between different servicereqno... Anyway as I said the OP's question is a bit too vague on that matter.

Comment: @TT, yes it is vague on that point. I initially left it out for simplicity but I have now edited the code as suggested and also added the `servicereqno` to the `JOIN` so that it returns correct results.

Comment: thank you for you feedback, as new to this i am unsure as to why this is not working for me, i am getting the ROWNUMBER and over is not valid ROW_NUMBER is but i don't know what to change OVER to.

Comment: @AJ1791 That should be alright, here's the reference (for SQL Server 2008): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server provides [a built-in DATEDIFF function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx), which you can use to find the difference between two dates. Furthermore, SQL Server has [a built-in AVG function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx) that you can use to calculate the average of a set of values..

Comment: I think that does not really answer the question, since it leaves out how to actually get the duration between events.

Comment: It seemed to me like the question is about how to get the difference between two times. The question's title is "Date difference between events in same column" and the post ends with "My first task will be to determine what the difference in time is". The `DATEDIFF` function will accomplish this. I will edit my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: Dan, the point is "in the same column" - how do you apply `DATEDIFF()` to multiple rows?

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question.